# Necesito ayuda con el siguiente ejercicio

Tags: python

En Python tengo que realizar un ejercicio que consta de lo siguiente debo "Escribe una función que reciba dos strings (de largo > 2) como parámetros, y retorne un string de largo 4 que consista de las dos primeras letras del primer string y las últimas dos letras del segundo."

y pues estoy mas perdido que un moco en una oreja, me encantaría si me pueden ayudar?

```
def mezclador(string_a, string_b):
    while len(string_a) >= 2 and len(string_b) >= 2:
        string_c = string_a[0:1] + string_b[-1:-2]
    return string_c


string_a = input("ingrese palabra a: ")
string_b = input("ingrese palabra b: ")

print(mezclador(string_a, string_b))
```

Comment: Las 2 últimas letras del segundo son en reversa o normal... Me explico:  1ra palabra: Queso, 2da: Pizza... Resultado: Quza  o  Quaz  ??

Comment: ¿Cuál se supone que es la pregunta?

Comment: Hola Diego, te sugiero que le des una vuelta a tu código y pienses otra manera de hacerlo. Tu código se bloquea infinitamente dentro del bucle `while` porque la condición nunca cambia. Cada vuelta del bucle siempre es `True` cuando tengan ambas dos caracteres porque el tamaño de las dos cadenas es inmutable (nunca cambia).

Comment: @JoseRodriguez te agradezco por las correcciones, me gana la pereza en algunas cosas por la hora, muy gentil por eso. y muchas gracias por los consejos, creo que lo logre finalmente gracias a la ayuda de todos uds. de veras, que pena lo canson que sere pero soy muy muy novato, no tengo nada que ver con programación y me dio por empezar y creo que lo lograre, en parte por la colaboración que este tipo de foros permite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptando tu codigo queda de la siguiente forma:

```
def mezclador(string_a, string_b):
     if len(string_a) >= 2 and len(string_b) >= 2:
         string_c = string_a[0:2] + string_b[-3:-1]
         return string_c
     else:
         return "Los strings deben tener al menos 2 letras"
     
string_a = input("ingrese palabra a: ")
string_b = input("ingrese palabra b: ")

print(mezclador(string_a , string_b))
```

ten ojo que en python tu [0:1] llega hasta el 0 ya que el de cierre no es inclusivo

Comment: Bueno pues chicos, la verdad estoy super agradecido, claro que si, ambos métodos me funcionaron, y muchas gracias por los consejos. La verdad es que esto de ser novato es difícil. en pyCharm funciono perfecto, increíble y muchas gracias pero en la pagina de la tarea me dice que hay un error. pero lo voy a dejar asi.

Answer (score 0):

Diego prueba este código:

```
def mezclador(string_a, string_b):
    string_c = string_a[0:2] + string_b[:-3:-1]
    return string_c

def mezclador2(string_a, string_b):
    string_c = string_a[0:2] + (string_b[:-3:-1])[::-1]
    return string_c

string_a = input("ingrese palabra a: ")
string_b = input("ingrese palabra b: ")


while len(string_a) < 2 or len(string_b) < 2:
    print('Ingrese las palabras mayores de 2 carácteres')
    string_a = input("ingrese palabra a: ")
    string_b = input("ingrese palabra b: ")

print(mezclador(string_a, string_b))

print(mezclador2(string_a, string_b))
```

Como no sabía en la segunda palabra si las letras iban en normal o en reversa, te coloque en el código las dos funciones distintas que hacen cada trabajo.. Pude colocarlas en una sola función, pero preferí separarlas para que puedas entender el código..

Verifica este enlace que te ayudará con Slicing, así podrás entender mucho mejor cómo realizar esta técnica:

[https://www.journaldev.com/23584/python-slice-string#:~:text=The%20slicing%20starts%20with%20the,for%20any%20index%20'i'.](https://www.journaldev.com/23584/python-slice-string#:%7E:text=The%20slicing%20starts%20with%20the,for%20any%20index%20%27i%27.)

Nos comentas como te fue

Comment: hola, muchas gracias, estaba un poco confundido pero me aclaraste mucho, creo que no estaba TAAAN perdido, sin embargo hay algo en la pagina de la tarea que me dice que tiene un error pero no importa aprendi un montón, esto de ser novato y no tener nada que ver con programación mas que ganas es difícil, muchas gracias de veras y espero me aguanten por que seguiré preguntando.